# Target every other single li within multiple lists

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I hope this isn't posted somewhere else, I sure couldn't find it. Not even sure how to explain it in a search...Essentially I want to target every other "content 1", say so that they all have alternating backgrounds. It is easy enough to target every second li element with nth:child, however I cannot figure out how to select EVERY OTHER li child from different lists so that "a" and "c" have dark backgrounds while "b" and "d" have the default styling.

```
<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content 1</li> //a//
</ul>

<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content 1</li> //b//
</ul>

<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content 1</li> //c//
</ul>

<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content 1</li> //d//
</ul>
```

Edit: I am trying to do this within a Wordpress installation, specifically to the featured image within the built in blogs template. So the li elements are generated dynamically, therefor I don't have the direct ability to add a class to the li element. While I could in theory edit the php, I was hoping there was a way to target via CSS...

Answer (score 0):

You're overcomplicating it, severely.

CSS:

```
.alt-row {
    background-color : #DDD;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content 1</li> //a//
</ul>

<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li class="alt-row">content 1</li> //b//
</ul>

<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li>content 1</li> //c//
</ul>

<ul>
<li>content</li>
<li class="alt-row">content 1</li> //d//
</ul>
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should have given more information. I am trying to do this within a Wordpress installation, specifically to the featured image within the built in blogs template. So the li elements are generated dynamically, therefor I don't have the direct ability to add a class to the li element. While I could in theory edit the php, I was hoping there was a way to target via CSS...

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply call it up by this piece of code:

```
ul:not(:first-child) > li:nth-of-type(2){
    color: red;
}
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/C2B6h/)